# Plot multiple curves from rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this dataframe:

[image]

and I need to have a chart similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mQJb.png

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this documentation on plotting with pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html
Then potting simply works like `df.plot()` plus some additional lines depending on color, axis labels, etc.

Additional remark: you should not post data as image. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask